# Bluetooth headphone sound fades out at low volumes

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I've recently bought some Conwin E7 wireless headphones, and have also bought a bluetooth transmitter (FirstE Portable Wireless Bluetooth Transmitter) to plug into the headphone jack on my computer. At high volumes, the performance is good. At low volumes, however, the volume kind of fades out to silence.

So, in a loud part of a song I can hear everything very well. At a quieter part of a song, I can't hear anything (but there is definitely supposed to be some sound). It's as if my computer doesn't output any signal for sounds below, say, 20% of max volume. There is similar behaviour when I pair the headphones with my iPhone, so the issue may not be with my computer but rather with my headphones. However, I wondered if there was some way to make the computer output audio signal regardless of the volume, or something like that?

They work perfectly if I plug them into the audio jack on the computer.

I'm using 16.04 on an HP Elitedesk.

Any suggestions?

Thanks